# Regex replace non-word except dash

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern `(\W|_)[^-]` doesn't work for `h_e.l_l.o - w_o.r_d` (replacement string is " ").

It returns something like this:

```
h      w
```

I hope to see at least something like this:

```
h e l l o - w o r d
```

How can I replace all non-word characters and `_` excluding the `-` symbol?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: @user2648694 When  you come back, please consider checking the answer below and if it works, accepting it.

Answer (score 16):

To match any non-word char except dash (or hyphen) you may use

```
[^\w-]
```

*However*, this regular expression does not match `_`.

You need a *negated character class* that matches any char other than letters, digits and hyphens:

```
/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

or (with a case insensitive modifier):

```
/[^-a-z0-9]+/i
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC6iJ8/3).

Note that the `-` is placed at the character class start, and does not require escaping.

You may add a plus at the end to match all the unwanted characters at a stretch to remove them in one go.

If you want to make your pattern Unicode aware (that is, in some regex flavors, if you use shorthand character classes with/without some flags, they will also match all Unicode counterparts), you may use

```
/[^\w-]|_/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC6iJ8/4) (or `/(?:[^\w-]|_)+/` to grab the whole chunk of these chars).

Here, `[^\w-]` matches any char that is not a word char (letter, digit, or underscore) and the second alternative `_` matches underscores.

Comment: big thanks :) It helps me alot PS. Actually this [^a-zA-Z0-9-] will work in all needed situation

Comment: @user2648694: I updated the answer with the description and possible variations.